# Update if count is greater than 5 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to create a query that'll update `table_1` where column `id_owner` has more than `5 rows` with the same `owner id`, it needs to set column "`active`" to `3` on all rows those users have.

I've tried several different methods and turned up empty with each. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your sql normally your where cause has just to match all related rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `UPDATE` query with `JOIN` to achieve this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT id_owner
      FROM table1
     GROUP BY id_owner
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
  ) t2
  ON t1.id_owner = t2.id_owner
  SET t1.active = 3;
```

#### See [this sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9a5b7b/1)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:-

```
update table_1
set active = 3
where owner_id in
(
  select * from
  (
    select owner_id
    from table_1
    group by owner_id
    having count(*) > 5
  ) a
)
```

Comment: Hi. [We can not target the same table for update in MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ed02/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
update table_1
set active = 3
where owner_id in
(
  select * from
  (
    select owner_id
    from table_1
    group by owner_id
    having count(*) > 5
  ) x
)
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7ab3/1)

Comment: Hi. [We can not target the same table for update in MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ed02/1).

Comment: I thought that is only for delete. Thanks for the fiddle.